# Convert world to screen coordinates with camera position and camera angle

Tags: math, matrix, opengl, graphics, game-development

I'm trying to convert world coordinates to screen coordinates. I have available: fov, screen width, screen height, camera position, camera angle and obviously the position of the object in world space.

This is what I tried:

```cpp
glm::vec3 world_to_screen(glm::vec3 pos,
                          glm::vec3 cam_angle,
                          glm::vec3 cam_pos) {
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(
        glm::radians(FOV), (float)SCREEN_W / (float)SCREEN_H, NEAR, FAR);

    glm::mat4 model(1.0);

    model = glm::translate(model, cam_pos);

    model = glm::rotate(model, cam_angle.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, cam_angle.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, cam_angle.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    glm::mat4 view = glm::inverse(model);

    glm::mat4 modelview = view * model;

    return glm::project(pos, modelview, projection,
                        glm::vec4(0, 0, SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H));
}
```

However it is not working, the output screen coordinates are over 30000 (I don't have a 30k monitor...) and I'm not sure what I did wrong.

There is a correlation though, sometimes the screen coordinates happen to be in my screen (I draw an indicator at the position to see if I did it right) and if the object moves the indicator also moves with (kinda) the same speed etc.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: "However it is not working, the output screen coordinates are over 30000 (I don't have a 30k monitor...) and I'm not sure what I did wrong." Nothing in `glm:project` prevents the projection of off-screen points. There are too many unknowns to find the issue. For example, what exactly is `cam_angle`? For an euler style rotation, there are 6 different possibilities. Also, is it degree or radians? What value is `pos` and which result do you actually _expect_?

Comment: Answered it more or less under your answer. I expect the indicator be on my object as it moves and the pos are coordinates from the origin, e.g. (200, -20, 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

> ```
> glm::mat4 view = glm::inverse(model);
>
> glm::mat4 modelview = view * model;
> ```

is equivalent to `glm::mat4 modelview(1.0f)` (except for floating point inaccuracies).

The *modelView* matrix in computer graphics refers to the product of the *view* matrix **of the camera** and the *model* matrix  **of the object you want to render**. What you calculated is the model matrix of the *camera* (if you would want to place some 3D object into your world at the position of your camera). You typically do not want to do that. And rendering an object with the model matrix of the camera means it has to cancel itself out, as the center of the object would be transformed to the position of the camera, which is the origin of the *eye space*.

However, since your `pos` is given in world space, your model matrix of the object is implicitly the identity matrix, hence

```
glm::mat4 modelview = view;
```

is what you need here.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Kinda forgot what the inverse actually means and like this it obviously makes no sense... Implemented it, and it looks quite good, at least I see my indicator now, but I think something is off with the angle. My camera angle is in degrees -> pitch, yaw, roll. I tried converting them with glm::radians but it still doesn't work. Do I need to do additional conversions, what format does glm expect?

Comment: Also, what exactly does glm::project take? The parameter is called "model" but in the docs they called it modelview?

Comment: Well, `glm::project(...,model,proj,..)` will internally calculate `inverse(proj * model)`. So  only the product of those two matrix arguments will matter. If you want to go from window space to world space, setting `model` as `view` and `proj` as your projection matrix is the most obvious choice (although you could also set one of the two to `proj * view` and the other to identity and still get the same result)

Comment: If your data is yaw, pitch, roll in degrees, you are missing the `glm::radians()`, and your matrix multiplication order is probably wrong.

Comment: Wait, you said going from window to world space... But I want to do the exact opposite?

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. `project` of course goes from world to window space, what I wrote above was for `unproject`, but the rest still applies as I wrot eit

Comment: ah ok. what exactly do you mean with "your matrix multiplication order is probably wrong"? how should i do it then?

Comment: it all depends on the convetions you use. Rx*Ry*Rz as you currently do it is probably wrong for the most typical yaw-pitch-roll convention

Comment: It's vec3(pitch, yaw, roll) (in that order). (89 0 0) is looking straight down. (0 20 0) is 20 degrees left from (0 0 0). (0 -20 0) is 20 degrees right from (0 0 0).
In what order would I need to do it then?

Comment: well, the interesting point with rotation matrix multiplication order isn't what (x,0,0), (0,y,0) and (0,0,z) are, but what (x,y,z) is when none is zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230760/discussion-between-itsame-and-derhass).